# R - merging variables and strings

Tags: r, function, parsing

I created R function for loading data from my db. Part of that function looks like this

```
cars <- function(sk) {
    get_data <- tbl(ff_ba, "sk_cars") %>%
      filter(id %in% sk_cars_ids$id) %>%
      collect()
  return(get_data)
}
```

I´d like to allow users to change all that occurrences of "sk" in my code with parsing parameter in my function. Usually I use for merging variables and strings paste() function but I didnt discovered how to do that here.

For example, if user call will call the function like this

```
cars(us)
```

Code inside the function should be

```
get_data <- tbl(ff_ba, "us_cars") %>%
          filter(id %in% us_cars_ids$id) %>%
          collect()
      return(get_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to your database I can't confirm that this works, but I think you'll be able to use `deparse(substitute())` and `get()` to do what you want. Here is a silly example using the `mtcars` dataset.

First, some filtering dataframes, that take the place of your `x_cars_ids` dataframes:

```
mpg_values <- data.frame(values = c(27.3, 30.4, 33.9))
disp_values <- data.frame(values = 100:300)
```

Now the function, with details in comments:

```
custom_filter <- function(prefix) {
  # Convert the input to a string value
  input <- deparse(substitute(prefix))

  # Use get to call the correct filtering df
  filter_df <- get(paste(input, "_values", sep = ""))

  # Subset using the string value
  out <- mtcars[mtcars[input] > 25, ] %>%
    # filter using the df called by 'get', treating
    # the input as our desired filtering variable
    # just for this example
    filter(get(input) %in% filter_df$values)
  return(out)
}
```

Now calling that function with the appropriate variable name will filter mtcars based on that variable:

```
> custom_filter(mpg)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
2 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
3 27.3   4 79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
4 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2


> custom_filter(disp)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
6 19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
7 21.4   4  121 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.